# If the weak energy condition is violated, can the area of ​the event horizon decrease?

Tags: thermodynamics, event-horizon, cosmic-censorship

The second law of black hole mechanics asserts

$$\text{WCC} + \text{WEC}\Longrightarrow\delta A \geq 0 \tag{1}$$
where WCC = weak cosmic censorship, WEC = weak energy condition and A   = event horizon cross section area. Since the only equivalent implication is

$$\delta A<0 \Longrightarrow\;\overline{\text{WCC+WEC}}$$

My question is: is this relation generalizable to a logical equivalence of the type $\Longleftrightarrow$ such as, by violating the WEC or the WCC, is it possible that $A$ decreases (locally)?

---

[1] S.W.Hawking, *The Nature of Space and Time*, p.16-17. Princeton University Press, arXiv:hep-th/9409195, September 30, 1994.

Url: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9409195v1

Comment: Clearly, not any violation of the WEC would automatically lead to a violation of the area theorem. Trivially, you can violate the WEC in  a part of the spacetime far away from the horizon, and this would do exactly nothing to the horizon area.